# mongodb data recover: I just copy the /var/lib/mongodb folder

Tags: mongodb

I just copy the /var/lib/mongodb folder  and the mongodb is running. Can i  copy the folder to the new server  just set the new mongo server data path to the folder?

Answer (score 2):

Don't do directly copy running server db path, When you try to copy data path while running may be data crash/corrupting happend.

So please follow the below mentioned steps,

- Stop the mongod server which one you want to copy data path server
- Copy the the **/var/lib/mongodb folder**
- Copy to new enviornment/Server
- Remove the mongod.lock file
- Start the new and currently stopped server

Now you check both places, your're having same data sets.